# How To Get The Root Directory Of an Elixir Project

Tags: elixir

In an Elixir project, you can use

```
Path.expand
```

to define a file or directory as a relative path from the current file.

For example: `Path.expand("../../../lib/file.ex")`

but how about finding a path from the root level of the project?

Comment: Some others visiting here might find the following useful: [`:code.priv_dir`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1) or [`:code.lib_dir`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#lib_dir-0).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you'd like to get the project's root directory, use

```
File.cwd!
```

source: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elixir-lang-talk/Ls0eJDdMMW8

*(note: I pulled this here only so it's not buried in a dead forum behind Google auth wall & subject to Google data preservation policies)*

Comment: Actually, [cwd](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.5.3/File.html#cwd/0) this is not the project's root directory. This is the current working directory (which might be different)

Comment: @Motine did you read the forum discussion? Jose states, "if the project is being compiled with Mix, "File.cwd!" will always point to the root directory because Mix always runs from root."

Comment: Yep. But I actually did not use mix.

Comment: I'm working on an umbrella project. I'm using a module from another app in the umbrella; a call to `File.cwd!` in the dependency app returns the root of the running app, not the root of the dependency app.

Answer (score 5):

In case of an umbrella app, you can create a key in your config.exs file :

```
config :some_app,
  project_root: File.cwd!
```

And then use that value from wherever you want in your project :

```
project_root = Application.fetch_env!(:some_app, :project_root)
```