# Phoenix Framework / Elixir, output relative file path to the console

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How to log the relative file location to its project root?

"my-project" is the root directory of the Phoenix Framework project.
Inside `users/me/apps/my-project/my-file.txt`, if I do :

`IO.puts __ENV__.file`

The console outputs the absolute path: `users/me/apps/my-project/my-file.txt`.

How to output the relative path, e.g. `my-project/my-file.txt`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the root directory [using `File.cwd!()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45910386/320615) and then do a leading trim of `__ENV__.file` with it:

```
defmodule A do
  def a do
    __ENV__.file |> String.trim_leading(File.cwd!)
  end
end
```

Sample output:

```
iex(1)> A.a
"/lib/a.ex"
```

Comment: is File.cwd! always the "project" directory ( where the app was compiled ), or is it the directory where the compiled app is running ?

Comment: `File.cwd!` at run time will point to the directory you're running `mix` from. If you want it to always point to its own project's root (which I think you do), you can call the function at compile time: `@cwd File.cwd!()` and then use `@cwd`.